# Cannot open symmetric key with two update triggers

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

Using SQL Server, I have two after update triggers.  One that uses a symmetric key and another that updates a lastModified field.  Without the last modified trigger everything works fine, but when I have it I get this error:

> The key 'NHAES_Key01' is not open. Please open the key before using
>   it."

I assume the last modified trigger is causing the trigger that needs the key to fire and this is using a different security context, but I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have two triggers for the same event? You should combine them into a single trigger. When you have multiples you have to set the trigger order and maintenance of everything just gets way complicated. And of course since you didn't post any actual code the best we can do is make educated guesses.

Comment: @SeanLange: "have to set the trigger order" is strong, no? If the concerns are orthogonal, the order might not matter.

Comment: @BenThul you could be correct. But two triggers on the same event is not a great design. It just adds complexity with no benefit.

Comment: There is a reason I have two triggers.  I understand that merging it into one trigger will solve the problem but that causes other issues.